# setVelocity engine cannot be applied to org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactoryBean

Tags: java, spring, velocity, spring-java-config

This is the Java configuration file I wrote. I found following error in velocityEngine in SimpleRegistrationService method.

```
setVelocity engine(org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine)in SimpleRegistrationService cannot be applied to org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactoryBean
```

And near "resource.loader=class", I'm getting this error

```
 setVelocityProperties(java.util.Properties) in VelocityEngineFactory cannot be applied to (java.lang.String, java.lang.String)
 
 <interface declaration>, <parcelable declaration>, AidlTokenType.import or AidlTokenType.package expected, got 'resource
```

Please help solving the errors.

```
package com.vlclabs.adsops.configuration;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl;
import com.vlclabs.adsops.service.SimpleRegistrationService;
import org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine;
import org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactoryBean;

@Configuration
public class EmailConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender() {
        JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
        mailSender.setHost("mail.csonth.gov.uk");
        return mailSender;
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleRegistrationService registrationService(JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender, VelocityEngineFactoryBean velocityEngine) {
        SimpleRegistrationService registrationService = new SimpleRegistrationService();
        registrationService.setMailSender(mailSender);
        registrationService.setVelocityEngine(velocityEngine);
        return registrationService;
    }

    @Bean
    public VelocityEngineFactoryBean velocityEngine() {
        VelocityEngineFactoryBean velocityEngine = new VelocityEngineFactoryBean();
        velocityEngine.setVelocityProperties("resource.loader=class", "class.resource.loader.class=org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader");
        return velocityEngine;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are misusing the velocityProperties, it should look like this:

```
@Bean
public VelocityEngineFactoryBean velocityEngine() {
    VelocityEngineFactoryBean velocityEngine = new VelocityEngineFactoryBean();

    Properties velocityProperties = new Properties();
    velocityProperties.put("resource.loader", "class");
    velocityProperties.put("class.resource.loader.class", "org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader");
    velocityEngine.setVelocityProperties(velocityProperties);

    return velocityEngine;
}
```

Since your velocityEngine is a Spring FactoryBean, and not the concrete `VelocityEngine` you want to use, you either need to call the `getObject()` method on the factoryBean, or inject the `VelocityEngine` itself, so Spring will call `getObject()` for you:

```
@Bean
public SimpleRegistrationService registrationService(JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender, VelocityEngineFactoryBean velocityEngine) {
    SimpleRegistrationService registrationService = new SimpleRegistrationService();
    registrationService.setMailSender(mailSender);
    registrationService.setVelocityEngine(velocityEngine.getObject()); // <--- getObject
    return registrationService;
}
```

or

```
// VelocityEngine as parameter type, not VelocityEngineFactoryBean
@Bean
public SimpleRegistrationService registrationService(JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender, VelocityEngine velocityEngine) { 
    SimpleRegistrationService registrationService = new SimpleRegistrationService();
    registrationService.setMailSender(mailSender);
    registrationService.setVelocityEngine(velocityEngine); // <-- no getObject() needed
    return registrationService;
}
```

See this blogpost by the brilliant Josh Long for details regarding FactoryBeans: https://spring.io/blog/2011/08/09/what-s-a-factorybean

Comment: Thank you its working. But how about the first error?

Comment: And I want to know whether my return statements are correct as well.

Comment: Updated my answer